# Code in each controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller and every method of it starts with the following code:

```
@user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])

if @user == nil
  redirect_to(:controller=> 'user_data', :action=> 'login')
  return
end
```

I'm just wondering if it is possible to avoid code duplication in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :check_user

  def check_user
  ..
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_logged_in

  # actions here.

  def ensure_logged_in
    @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])

    if @user == nil
      redirect_to(:controller=> 'user_data', :action=> 'login')
    end
  end
end
```

You shouldn't need to worry about the 'return', as rails will bail out of the filter pipeline once the redirect happens.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplication you just need to add before_filter in every controller where you want to check user authentication.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :authenticate_user

end
```

then add your user authentication logic in application controller something like this,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser]) if session[:cuser]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authenticate_user
    redirect_to({:controller=> 'user_data', :action=> 'login'}, :alert => "Not authorized") if current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

You can use current_user helper method in every controller to get current user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [before filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter). This should be fine